# User can't able to share document

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions, document, share

My document library has unique permissions.

On this library I have given `Full Control` to one user only. But that user does not having Full control and edit permissions over site.

Now when user upload the document and click on share then he is getting access required error

> Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

What permission is needed for 'Share'?